# Calculate length of module

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be the ring $ A := \mathbb{R}[X] / (X^3 - X^2 + X -1)$. How would I go about calculating $l_{\mathbb{R[X]}}(A)$ the length of $A$ as $\mathbb{R[X]}$ module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The submodule of $A$ correspond to the ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ containing $(X^3-X^2+X-1)=((X-1)(X^2+1))$, which are $\mathbb{R}[X], (X-1), (X^2+1)$ and $((X-1)(X^2+1))$. Since the maximal chain of ideals is $((X-1)(X^2+1)) \subset (X-1) \subset \mathbb{R}[X]$ (or $((X-1)(X^2+1)) \subset (X^2+1) \subset \mathbb{R}[X]$), the length is $3$.

Comment: Sorry, is the notation I used $\mathbb{R}/(X^3 - X^2 + X - 1)$ even correct? Or should it be $\mathbb{R}/(X^3 - X^2 + X - 1)\mathbb{R}[X]$. Thank you!

Comment: I think the notation you used in the question $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^3-X^2+X-1)$ is correct.  The notation $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^3-X^2+X-1)\mathbb{R}[X]$ is also fine.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since ideal $I=(x^3-x^2+x-1)$ is contained in two maximal ideals $m_1=(x-1)$ and $m_2=(x^2+1)$ we can construct (at least) two composition series. Notice that $I=m_1m_2=m_1\cap m_2$ since $m_1$ and $m_2$ are coprime $m_1+m_2=R:=\mathbb{R}[x]$. First composition series is
$$
0=M_0 \subset M_1=m_2/I \subset M_2=R/I.
$$
In this case $M_2/M_1 \cong R/m_2 \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $M_1 = m_2/m_1 \cap m_2\cong (m_1+m_2)/m_1 = R/m_1 \cong \mathbb{R}$. Second composition series is
$$
0=M_0 \subset M_1=m_1/I \subset M_2=R/I.
$$
So, $M_2/M_1 \cong R/m_1 \cong \mathbb{R}$ and $M_1 = m_1/m_1 \cap m_2\cong (m_1+m_2)/m_2 = R/m_2 \cong \mathbb{C}$.

We can see that quotients are isomorphic but permuted as predicted by Jordan-Holder theorem. But in any case, the length is two $\ell_R(R/I)=2$.